# Where is the Spree 4.4 frontend?

Tags: spree

I installed Spree 4.4 I can't find any frontend At localhost:3000 it says Yay You're on Rails The docs say to download the frontend api and open it in Postman I did that but I didn't see anything that looks like a storefront I can get to the admin panel alright Anyone can help?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking at the port for the Rails API, not the frontend. Which docs are you reading? A link would help understand the issue.

Comment: github.com/spree/spree An admin panel is reachable at localhost:4000/admin

Comment: What do you see on port 4000? The question says you're looking for the frontend on port 3000, but the quote you shared says 4000.

Answer (score 0):

Spree 4.4 is a headless commerce. If you want to add storefront to your application using this [SDK](https://github.com/spree/spree-storefront-api-v2-js-sdk) you can create your own or use one of the pre-built starters:

- [Next.js](https://dev-docs.spreecommerce.org/storefronts/next.js-commerce)
- [Vue Storefront](https://dev-docs.spreecommerce.org/storefronts/vue-storefront)

If you want to use [spree legacy storefront](https://github.com/spree/spree_legacy_frontend), you can add this extension too in your gemfile and you are able to navigate storefront directly. [ Please note this extension is in maintenance mode, it might have some issues ]

Also, please make sure on which port you are running your application.
By default rails application runs on port `3000`.

So you can navigate spree:

Admin Panel: `http://localhost:3000/admin`

StoreFront: `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: I had a running server from  running ```bin/setup``` but I stopped it with ctrl-c How do I start it again?

Comment: It looks you are using dockerized version of spree and using [spree_starter](https://github.com/spree/spree_starter). If you need to add the storefront, you need to install the spree without docker and add gem [spree_legacy_frontend](https://github.com/spree/spree_legacy_frontend) and then run `rails s`. 

Create a rails application and install spree by following this doc - 
https://dev-docs.spreecommerce.org/advanced/existing_app_tutorial

Comment: I opted for vuestorefront/spree I'm having problems with 4.4 headless backend now Frontend's not a problem anymore as it was when I posted this question The problem I'm having is it can't write to development.log due to perms

Comment: Following your question, if the above answer helps you, please vote for it. Regarding the rails server, did you try running again `bin/setup`. Also, you can post your question separately if you face any other issue and you can add development log too there for details .

Comment: The server runs  but ```rails db:reset``` fails aborted core dumped I also don't understand why seed data doesn't show in admin panel I was trying to remove the seed data